# Narrowing down memory leak

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

I am still searching for a way to solve my memory leaks. For the moment I have a leak at this line of code.

```
return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Anybody an idea?

Thx in advance!

```
- (UIImage *)imageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    // use "imageWithContentsOfFile:" instead of "imageNamed:" here to avoid caching our images
    NSString *imageName = [self imageNameAtIndex:index];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
    //NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"jpg"];

    return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
}

- (void)configurePage:(ImageScrollView *)page forIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

{

```
page.index = index;
page.frame = [self frameForPageAtIndex:index];

// To use full images instead of tiled images, replace the "displayTiledImageNamed:" call
// above by the following line:
// [page displayImage:[self imageAtIndex:index]];
[page displayImage:[self imageAtIndex:index]];
```

}

Comment: How are you calling this method?

Comment: I agree the static analyzer is your friend here.

Comment: You can't have a leak in one line.  A leak is always the result of a combination of circumstances.

Comment: I added the code for [self imageNameAtindex:index] and I ran the analyser. I already posted this here, but can't seem to figure it out :s http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771851/potential-leak-of-an-object-allocated-on-line-123-and-stored-into-page

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted.   It is a common question with a common misconception.

Answer (score 3):

When leaks identifies a line of code as being a leak, it is **not claiming that said line of code is the actual leak**.   Only that said line of code is *the source of the allocation that was leaked*.

Thus, the image returned by `imageWithContentsOfFile:` is being over-retained somewhere else and it is your job to find out where.

Which is generally pretty easy;   turn on the "retain tracking" [IIRC] checkbox on the little configuration panel of the Allocations instrument, run your app, and then click through one of the leaked UIImages to see a list of exactly where the image was retained and released.   One of those retains will not be balanced and that is your leak.

Though slightly orthogonal, I describe how to do this in a post about using [Heapshot Analyais](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/) to find leaks.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've just poured myself a cup of coffee, which I should have done before answering.